# Search wildcard tag loses tags for unanswered

Tags: bug, search

When I have a favorite like `linq*` and I click the Favorite, and I am viewing `Unanswered` or I then click `Unanswered`, the search changes to just be for `[linq]`. Why is this and how can I work around it?